# Return to a different function from Handler Mode

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-m

When I am in handler mode due to an exception, I am evaluating some conditions and deciding if return to thread mode to the same function, or to a different one, just to return to the original after being done.

Initially, I wanted to do like with the Cortex R4 and switch from Interrupt mode to Privileged mode.

```
mrs R1,CPSR       ; Save the Interrupt Mode registers
cps #19           ; Switch to privilege mode
 ....             ; do your thing
msr CPSR_CXSF, R1 ; Return to interrupt mode
```

But now I am using a Cortex M7

I have tried doing

```
  OriginalLR = *(int*)(__get_PSP() + 0x18); 
  ptr_p = (int*)(__get_PSP() + 0x18);
  *ptr_p = MyDummyFunction;
```

Then in MyDummyFunction I push all the registers, "do my thing" and restore all the registers.

```
 asm(" STMFD R13!,{R0-R12}");
 ... ; doing my thing
 asm(" LDMFD R13!,{R0-R12}");
```

But I have no idea how to return, If I exit or BL, then it POP's stuff from the stack. Changing the PC seems dangerous.

Any suggestion? I guess I cannot change from Handler Mode to Thread Mode within the function as in the Cortex R4?

Comment: I've looked at both technical reference manual and the architectural reference manual of the cortex armv7-m, but they only describe the way the transition between handler mode to thread mode. I have to admit that I don't know much about assembly. The issue is that I have no control about the code that is creating the exception frame, and the function could vary. So what you suggest its to save the state of the PSP (Process Stack Pointer) including the PC, and modify it and recover it afterwards? I could push it into the stack, but can I write directly into the PC when I am recovery the PSP?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?  Asking because it changes the answer.  The possibilities are (I think) because you want to ensure that the 'inserted' function runs without privilege, or because you want it to run with a lower priority than the exception handler, or that you want it to use the process stack (handler mode always uses the MSP on the Cortex-M).

Comment: Ahh if that is what you are asking, dont mess with the dual stack thing of a cortex-m, its a PITA.  Stick with one and sleep easier...and not all cortex-ms have the dual stack pointers.  Do it the easy way first then do some targeted experiments (throwaway code) to understand the dual stack implementation, then decide if it does what you thought and if you can find a use for it).

Comment: I thought you were porting code from an R4 to an M7, but think I see what you are asking now...

Comment: How you exit an interrupt depends on the EXC_RETURN value in the link register. You can make it exit to Thread or Handler mode using either the MSP or PSP stack pointer. I would used the MSP in handler mode and the PSP in thread mode. That way everything is handled for you. Don't confuse handler mode with privileged/unpriv. Handler mode is always privileged. The privileged / unpriv mode only applies to thread mode.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any more clarity about the use-case for this, I can give only a few possibilities for how this might be achieved.

On the Cortex-M family, there are generally three primary differences between thread mode and handler mode (note that differences exist between members of the Cortex-M family):

- Handler mode is always privileged.  Thread mode can be either privileged or unprivileged, depending on the setting of the nPRIV bit in the CONTROL register.  nPRIV is not available on Cortex-M0 and is optional on M0+ but exists on M3, M4 and M4F.
- Handler mode has a higher priority than thread mode.  Or rather, handlers have a higher priority than non-handler code, which amounts to the same thing.
- Handler mode always uses the main stack pointer (MSP) mirrored through r13 (SP).  Thread mode can be configured to mirror either the MSP or the process stack pointer (PSP) through SP, by using the SPSEL bit in the CONTROL register.  I'm pretty sure all Cortex-M devices have this arrangement - certainly the Cortex-M0, -M3 and -M4F devices I'm familiar with do and I can't find any reference to it being optional.  (This facility is designed to help with the implementation of context switches, which it does magnificently.)

It's not clear exactly why you want to ensure that your 'injected' function runs in thread mode - whether you wish to lower its priority, lower its privilege or have it use a different stack pointer.  So, here are some options.

### Option 1: None of the above

If you don't need to lower the priority of the injected function, and you don't need to swap stacks, and you don't care about running the injected function with privilege, then just call it before returning from the handler. It'll run in handler mode of course, but who cares?

### Option 2: It's about priority

If you want to ensure that your injected function can be interrupted by interrupt requests, for example, but you don't actually care about it being run in thread mode, *and* you're confident that the PendSV handler isn't being used for another purpose (it's the ideal place to put a context switch, so if you're using an OS then it's likely it is), then you can configure your function to be injected as the PendSV handler.

In your existing handler, setting the PendSV bit in the ICSR (Interrupt Control and Status Register) in the memory-mapped SCB (System Control Block) will cause the PendSV handler to be triggered, and it's generally configured to be the lowest-priority handler so it's executed once all other pending handlers have completed.  Note that the PendSV bit is reset automatically when the handler begins execution.

### Option 3: You really need thread mode

Well, this can be done, but it's complicated.  Some examples of the hurdles you face are:

- It's perfectly possible to poke the stack to force a handler to return to somewhere it didn't come from.  That's what a context switch does.  However you'd need to ensure that the exception handler could never be invoked from an interrupt handler before attempting this.
- At the end of the injected function, control must somehow be restored to the function that was interrupted, along with *all* of its volatile context including status flags and so on.  Assuming you can't write your injected function in a way that guarantees preservation of the status flags (which means no comparisons or tests!) then depending on your privilege configuration this could be tricky; the APSR (the part of the program status register where the status flags are held) is writeable only from privileged code.

I would suggest as a starting point (and I haven't tested this) that if you can be sure your exception handler can only be invoked from thread mode, you could:

1. Store the value of the thread-mode stack pointer somewhere safe.
2. Create a dummy stack frame and push it to the thread-mode stack, setting up the 'stacked' PC to force return to your injected function.
3. Return from the handler, which will force a return to thread mode and the invocation of the injected function.
4. At the end of the injected function, instead of returning, issue a SVC instruction to invoke a software interrupt handler.  This can be done from C using CMSIS.  (Note that if you can't control how the injected function is written, when creating the dummy stack frame you could initialise LR to force a branch to an SVC instruction at the end of the injected function.)
5. Write an SVC handler that restores the saved thread-mode stack pointer.  When that handler returns, the original interrupted function will be restored.

If you need to work with the possibility of interrupt handlers triggering your exception handler, you could implement the above in the PendSV handler.  Unless that's already being used... in which case I'm out of ideas.

I hope this gives you a starting point.

Comment: Hi @cooperised thank you for your reply. It had to be done via thread mode because I am using an OS. It turned out to be that I didn't have set the "Thumb Mode". So when returned to my address I had to give it a +1 offset, example: 0x90006d87 rather than 0x90000d686 (as the registry displays). This sets the thumb mode as 1. Trying to execute instructions without thumb mode result in an abort.

Comment: Correct.  I'm curious how you returned to executing the interrupted function though.